# setup svn and checkout

Tags: 12.04, svn

When i try to do svn checkout

using this  `svn co svn://ipAddress/var/svn/ulf/project myproject`

I get the error `svn: Can't connect to host 'ipAddress': Connection refused`

If I use `svn co svn+ssh://username@ipAddress/var/svn/ulf/project` 
it asks me for password after entering valid password

I get: `svn: Authentication failed`

I want to checkout using **htp://url/var/svn** need help ASAP

Note:

1. Putting svn/ folder under /var am I doing right?
2. I have given permission to ulf folder, which is my svn repos folder, which has conf/ db/ format/ locks/ hooks/ svn-commit.tmp

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you tried this `svn list --verbose http://host_name/svn_dir/repository_name/project` to see what it outputs?

Comment: got this svn: access to 'http://hostname/var/svn/ulf/project' forbidden

Comment: It is clear that you do not have the necessary rights. Make sure that you have configured subversion properly, and also make sure that you have been given the rights required to access the repository.

Comment: svn co svn://hostname/var/svn/ulf/project myproj --username abc im not geting any response , or not error wt wrong im doing